# How to set Paging for Xero's Payment API?

Tags: xero-api

There doesn't seem be an option to set the page quantity in the Payment endpoint for the GET method. I need to pull the data from every line item within a payment, but cannot see a workaround. Has anyone else come up with a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Hi @Casey and welcome to SO!

**According to Xero ([source](https://developer.xero.com/faq/limits/retrieving-data)):**

> You can use pagination to retrieve line item details for 100 items
>   (e.g. Invoices) at a time. Endpoints on the Accounting API that
>   currently support pagination are invoices, contacts, bank transactions
>   and manual journals. All major endpoints on the Payroll, Files and
>   Assets APIs also support paging. Use the If-Modified-Since header to
>   retrieve only what's changed since your previous request

However, regarding Payments, [Xero's API documentation](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/requests-and-responses) mentions how to filter or sort results but not how to paginate them, very surprising. [Back in 2012](https://community.xero.com/developer/discussion/71101) they officially confirmed this was not supported and considered it as a *Feature Request*.

**Here's a potential solution:**

I would use the 4th example in the *Retrieving a filtered set of resources using the “where” parameter* section here: https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/requests-and-responses and build a pagination myself using date ranges.

```
Date >= DateTime(2019, 01, 01) && Date < DateTime(2019, 01, 02)
Date >= DateTime(2019, 01, 02) && Date < DateTime(2019, 01, 03)
etc.
```

You might also consider achieving this using the `Reference` variable (assuming it has numerical values) which is available in the [Payments GET request](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/payments) too.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I appreciate the answer. I'll try that and see if it's a good solution, but do you think this will give me the multiple line items within the payment record? There is a lot more information in the payment that I will need which the "top-level" stuff (reference, invoice number, amount, contact into, etc) doesn't provide. Some of our bills have multiple line items that isn't given to me through the payment endpoint.

Comment: I'm not sure about that (I've never used Xero's API before) so that's just a guess.